# Can passing of WPF window in code consume too much RAM

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a WPF-application in which i can create and drag custom controls at run-time.
While moving over or dragging the custom controls i want to change the mouse cursor.
At the outskirts it works well, but when the mouse cursor is over the center of a custom control implementing a TextBox there is the normal editor-cursor.
Then i have found out that the changing can be done with the following code (example):

```
wpfwindow.Cursor = Cursor.ScrollAll;
Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursor.ScrollAll;
```

Now i wanted to export these lines to a static method in another class for common methods.

```
public static void DisplayCursor(Window window, Cursor displayCursor)
{
    window.Cursor = displayCursor;
    Mouse.OverrideCursor = displayCursor;
}
```

Because each time that method is called the WPF-window will be given as parameter i fear that it will decimate the RAM.
Is it true or not?
Or is it possible to override only the mouse cursor?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a reference to the window, there is no copying and therefore no additional RAM is used